# PHP cURL Problems: HTTP Code 0

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to bring up a website/API through cURL and PHP. Whatever URL I try I am getting an HTTP Code of 0. I have tried several different URLs. No matter what I try I am getting the following curl_getinfo back (see below). I have verified that cURL is enabled in PHP.ini file.

Code:

```
 // create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.yahoo.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);

$report=curl_getinfo($ch);
print_r($report);

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
curl_exec($ch);

if(curl_errno($ch)) {
   echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}

print curl_error($ch);

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
```

cURL_getinfo:

```
 Array
(
[url] => http://www.yahoo.com
[content_type] => 
[http_code] => 0
[header_size] => 0
[request_size] => 0
[filetime] => 0
[ssl_verify_result] => 0
[redirect_count] => 0
[total_time] => 0
[namelookup_time] => 0
[connect_time] => 0
[pretransfer_time] => 0
[size_upload] => 0
[size_download] => 0
[speed_download] => 0
[speed_upload] => 0
[download_content_length] => -1
[upload_content_length] => -1
[starttransfer_time] => 0
[redirect_time] => 0
[certinfo] => Array
    (
    )

[primary_ip] => 
[primary_port] => 0
[local_ip] => 
[local_port] => 0
[redirect_url] => 
 )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `curl_exec($ch);` before `curl_getinfo($ch);` cause this is the actual connection to the server:

also there is no need in the flag `CURLOPT_POST` since it's a get call:

```
// create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();

//for post calls:
//$post = 'a=b&d=c';
//$headers[] = 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8';
//$headers[] = 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($post);

//for get calls:
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-type: charset=utf-8'; 


$headers[] = 'Connection: Keep-Alive';

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.yahoo.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);

curl_exec($ch);
$report=curl_getinfo($ch);
print_r($report);

// grab URL and pass it to the browser


if(curl_errno($ch)) {
   echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}

print curl_error($ch);

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: That was perfect! Simple answer!! Been looking at this too long!